# Success on ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why is it that my code on Ajax success is not functioning.

**View**

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    // Populate the object with values
    $(document).on("click", "#btn_submit_schedule", function () {
        bootbox.confirm({
            title: "Save these details?",
            message: html,
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'YES',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'NO',
                    className: 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result === true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Member/CreateTicket',
                        data: obj,
                        succes: function (controlResult) {
                            console.log(controlResult);
                            if (controlResult === true) {
                                $.notify({
                                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                                    message: "Ticket has been saved"
                                }, {
                                    animate: {
                                        enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                                        exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    type: 'success'
                                });
                                $("#create_ticket_status").html("Created ticket successfully.");
                                chat.server.getPendingRequestCount(document.getElementById("selected_id").value);
                            } else {
                                $("#create_ticket_status").html(result);
                                $.notify({
                                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                                    message: "An error has occured on creating the ticket"
                                }, {
                                    animate: {
                                        enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                                        exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    type: 'success'
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $.notify({
                                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                                message: "Error has occured in creating ticket."
                            }, {
                                animate: {
                                    enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                                    exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                                }
                            }, {
                                type: 'success'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTicket(CreateTicket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var tm = new TicketManager();
        var controlResult = tm.CreateTicket(ticket);

        return controlResult ? Json(true) : Json("An error occured on creating the ticket.");
    }
    return Json("Fill-in the required fields.");
}
```

I can actually see the result as true in the reponse tab of the inspector and I can save in my database. Why the success function is not working, is beyond me. 
If I intentionally create an error, I can see the my error function works. Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: u mispelled succes , should be success

Comment: @Peter Thank you.

Comment: @Rory What do you mean? Can you show me a sample or a link maybe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo

> succes: function (controlResult) {

can you correct it and try as **success** with double s

Comment: Thank you for making me see that! I'll set it as answered after 11 minutes.