# Ajax call issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using the following code to receive some data from server. It always returns 200 ok with required data against my request. But it does not fire success or error event. If anybody can help me in that I'll be grateful to you.

```
$('body').on('click','a.btn_details',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var _id = $(this).attr('id');
            var _data = {'action': 'product_details','product_id':_id};
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../common/products.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: _data,
                succes: function (resp) {
                    alert(resp.name);
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(resp){
                    alert("xd,vj,dfjbj");
                }
            });
            $('#prd_list_cont').hide();
            $('#prd_det_cont').show();
        });
```

Thanks in advance,

Aisha Zafar

Comment: Aside from the typo in `success`, the show/hide may also go within the success callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Success on ajax not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152591/success-on-ajax-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your Ajax request. You need to replace `succes` with `success` :

```
success: function (resp) {
    alert(resp.name);
    return false;
},
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes efficient developers can do spelling mistakes :D

Answer (score 0):

**Can you correct it and try as success with double s**

```
    $('body').on('click','a.btn_details',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var _id = $(this).attr('id');
                var _data = {'action': 'product_details','product_id':_id};
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '../common/products.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: _data,
                    success: function (resp) {
                        alert(resp.name);
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function(resp){
                        alert("xd,vj,dfjbj");
                    }
                });
                $('#prd_list_cont').hide();
                $('#prd_det_cont').show();
            }

);
```